# RTC to BitBucket Migration

Tags: bitbucket, rtc

I am trying to migrate our source code from Rational Team concert to Bitbucket. So , I have created a branch in Bitbucket , then committed and pushed the entire RTC directory structure into Bitbucket.

The problem with this approach is that , I am unable to preserve the change history of individual files, when I push it to a Bitbucket branch.
So, what strategy should I take to preserve the change history in Bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

There is no RTC built-in tool for exporting the history (changeset after changeset, stream by stream) from RTC to a new Git repo.

You can try [**ljhaywar/rtc2git**](https://github.com/ljhaywar/rtc2git) ([mentioned here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/180989/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-jazz-scm-projects-to-git)) to see if you can export your RTC history that way. It does import baselines only:

> - It initalizes an empty git repository and clones it
> - In this repository, it loads a newly created rtc workspace based on your oldest stream
> - It iterates to a configured list of streams to determine the baseline of each component of this stream
> - For each baseline of this component a compare command will be executed
> - The result of the compare will be parsed to get to the necessary commit-informations (such as author, comment, date)
> - The change will be accepted in the workspace
> - The corresponding git command will be executed to do the same change in the git-repository